# YUV to RGB shader border artifact

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I have YUV to RGB conversion shader.

```
struct Pixel_INPUT
{
    float4 pos  : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex  : TEXCOORD0;
};

Texture2D textureY : register(t0);
Texture2D textureU : register(t1);
Texture2D textureV : register(t2);

SamplerState samstate
{
    MinFilter     = Anisotropic;
    MagFilter     = Anisotropic;
AddressU = Clamp;
AddressV = Clamp;
};

float4 PS(Pixel_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    float y = (1.1643f * textureY.Sample(samstate,input.tex) - 0.0625f);
    float u = textureU.Sample(samstate,input.tex) - 0.5f;
    float v = textureV.Sample(samstate,input.tex) - 0.5f;

   float r = y + 1.5958f * v;
   float g = y - 0.39173f * u - 0.81290f * v;
   float b = y + 2.017f * u;

   return float4(r,g,b,1);
}
```

But I have a green line at right side of image like that:
[image]

I use Clamp address mode and image is more yellow color than the original.

Comment: Aren't pixel centres 0,0 in D3D?

Comment: in D3D10 are  0.5 , 0.5 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: Perhaps more info needed.  Why is your picture a picture of the desktop?

Comment: I converted this image by some RGB to YUV tool and now I want to check my YUV to RGB shader.
do you see any mistake in my pixel shader?

Comment: This is clearly HLSL, what's with all the tags?

Comment: can you answer on my question?

Comment: No, you have not given enough information. While it is true that the coordinate range **[0.0, 1.0]** will sample off texel centers and that will mess with texture interpolation, it should actually be less of an issue at the edges than elsewhere given the clamp address mode. It's very unlikely that switching to point sampling, or correctly adjusting your texture coordinates will change anything (unless your Y, U and V resolution are different).

Comment: The problem is indeed unlikely to be in the shader. Please show the code that uses the shader (with  position and texture coordinates)

Comment: As a side note for yuv->rgb you don't need a sampler, Load with allow you to do get exact pixel coordinate instead. Also since Y is twice the resolution, and you use input.tex everywhere, you are likely also to sample in the wrong locations.

Answer (score 1):

I have sampler state

```
  samplerDesc.Filter   = D3D10_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC;
  samplerDesc.AddressU  = D3D10_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MIRROR;
  samplerDesc.AddressV   = D3D10_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MIRROR;
  samplerDesc.AddressW    = D3D10_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MIRROR;
  samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 8;
  samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_NEVER;


   pDevice->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc,&SampState);
```

About Y U and V textures resolution: U and V textures resolutions always are half of Y resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume (since you use a tri planar version for YUV) that your FourCC is I420 as described [here](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#IYUV)

Since SV_Position gives you the exact pixel coordinates, you can avoid using a Sampler (which should technically be in Point mode for this type of operations).

Here is a simple example to load your data in you use case (please note I only provide the loading code, not the conversion itself).

```
struct Pixel_INPUT
{
    float4 pos  : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex  : TEXCOORD0;
};

Texture2D textureY : register(t0);
Texture2D textureU : register(t1);
Texture2D textureV : register(t2);

float4 PS(Pixel_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    int3 pixelLocation = int3(input.pos.xy, 0)); //0 is miplevel

    //Get y component
    float y = textureY.Load(pixelLocation).r;

    //now since u and v are half resolution, we need to divide location by 2
    pixelLocation.xy /= 2;

    //Load our u and v components
    float u = textureU.Load(pixelLocation).r;
    float v = textureV.Load(pixelLocation).r;

    //Perform your conversion and return
}
```